# Is Haar measure faithful?

Tags: measure-theory, representation-theory

I was trying to use the answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42310/when-is-l2x-separable) to show that $L^p(G)$ and in particular $L^2(G)$ is separable for a compact group $G$, with which Peter-Weyl theorem implies that there is a countable discrete set of isomorphism classes of irreducible complex representations $G$.

Surprisingly I have done several search and found none mentions this.  Is it trivially true basically by definition?  I need a confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by *faithful* you mean that $f\geq0$ and $\int f\,d\mu=0$ implies that $f=0$ a.e., then this is true for any positive measure.

Let $f\geq0$ with $\int f\,d\mu=0$. Let 
$$
E_n=\{t:\ f(t)\geq1/n\}.
$$
Then
$$
\mu(E_n)=n\,\int_{E_n}\frac1n\leq n\,\int_{E_n}f\leq n\,\int f=0
$$
As $\{t:\ f(t)>0\}=\bigcup_nE_n$, we get that $\mu(\{f>0\})=0$. That is, $f=0$ $\mu$-a.e.